# Why is the duration of my transient simulation dictating my settling time in Pspice?

Tags: simulation, pspice, transient

I am doing a step response analysis of a Sallen-Key 2nd order filter. However, I find that the settling time given to me by Pspice using SettlingTime(V(Vout),2%) changes if I change the transient simulation duration.
Why is this?

Comment: Probably the timestep PSPICE is using is longer during the longer simulation times.  Try setting the maximum timestep to something reasonable and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Also try setting lower TRTOL or RELTOL, higher integration order (e.g. GEAR 2), etc. Or, I don't recall what all settings PSPICE has, maybe they are called differently or there are others. Try various settings and see which ones have effect.